# Backup laptop with Clonezilla to an external Blu-ray

Tags: linux, backup, windows-backup, clonezilla, blu-ray

I want to back up my Windows laptop to an external blu ray (LG BE14NU40); however, I can't get Clonezilla to recognize the blu-ray as a target.

I can see the drive show up in `dmesg` when I toggle the power on the blu-ray, but for some reason the blu-ray never shows up in the list of clonezilla mount options.

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

- Put a blank BD-R disc into the LG Blu-ray drive
- Stick the Clonezilla Live CD in my on-board DVD player and hit F3 to get the boot menu.  Then I boot from the DVD.

After Clonezilla boots...

[image: Clonezilla start screen]

[image: Select device-image]

[image: Select local-device]

[image: Toggle Blu-ray power]

When I see the prompt above, I toggle my blu-ray's power... but the drive won't show up.

The following `dmesg` demonstrates that at least the clonezilla linux kernel sees the usb hotplug event when I toggle power on the blu-ray.

```
user@vivid:~$ dmesg | tail -n4
[ 2911.449649] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-RAM        HL-DT-ST BD-RE  BE14NU40 1.01 PQ: 0 
ANSI: 0
[ 2911.557873] scsi 8:0:0:0 [sr1] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw
xa/form2 cdda tray
[ 2911.558257] scsi 8:0:0:0 Atached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 2911.558492] scsi 8:0:0:0 Atached scsi generic sg2 type 5
```

**QUESTION**

How can force clonezilla to use this blu-ray drive as a direct backup target?

---

**Details:**

- Laptop: [MSI PE060](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/PE60-2QE.html#hero-overview)
- Blu-ray: [LG BE14NU40](http://www.lg.com/us/data-storage/lg-BE14NU40)

I am running clonezilla vivid (stable), which is built on Ubuntu 15.0 (kernel 3.19.0-18-generic)... I see this when I boot the clonezilla iso and run a manual linux shell...

```
user@vivid:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 15.04 \n \l

user@vivid:~$ uname -a
Linux vivid 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@vivid:~$
```

Comment: You would have to write a patch to add this functionality.  The kernel is aware of the drive that does not mean it is aware of how to write to media using that drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I don't have a Blu-ray device to test with, but AFAIK this will work.*

**This will take a rewritable Blu-ray disc**
*If you have no rewritable Blu-ray discs, I think this is impossible, unless you are willing to mount a flash drive to `/home/partimag` for step 3 and burn the image to the Blu-ray with another computer.*

1. First, verify that your Blu-ray disc is formatted with Live File System/UDF, so that files can be added/removed as though it was a flash drive.
2. Then, instead of choosing `local_dev` to save the image to, choose `enter_shell`.
3. Once in the shell, insert your Blu-ray disc, and mount it to `/home/partimag`, by running `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /home/partimag` (I'm not sure if it is `sr0` for a Blu-ray...)
4. Now, type `exit`, and continue the cloning.
5. When the cloning is done, you should reboot or shutdown so that the Blu-ray is unmounted. Or you could go to the command line and run `sudo umount /home/partimag`.

P.S. I'm excited to know if this works for you. Sounds like it's been frustrating.

Comment: I can start a bonus after a couple days